# get equation of linear SVM regression line

Tags: r, svm, linear-regression, r-caret

I'm struggling to find a way to get the equation for a linear SVM model in the regression case, since most of the questions deal with classification... I have fit it with caret package.

## 1- univariate case

```
set.seed(1)
fit=train(mpg~hp, data=mtcars, method="svmLinear")
plot(x=mtcars$hp, y=predict(fit, mtcars), pch=15)
points(x=mtcars$hp, y=mtcars$mpg, col="red")
abline(lm(mpg~hp, mtcars), col="blue")
```

Which gives the plot with red=actual, black=fitted, and blue line is classic regression. In this case I know I could manually calculate the SVM prediction line from 2 points, but is there a way to get directly the equation from the model structure? I actually need the equation like this *y=a+b*x (here **mpg=?+?*hp** ) with values in the original scale.

[image]

## 2-multivariate

same question but with 2 dependent variables (`mpg~hp+wt`)
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I believe there is.  Take a look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/computing-the-decision-boundary-of-a-linear-svm-model), which is similar, but does not use the caret library.  If you add `svp = fit$finalModel`to the example, you should be able to follow it almost exactly.  I applied a similar technique to your data below.  I scaled the data to fit nicely on the plot of the vectors since the library scales the data at runtime.

```
require(caret)

set.seed(1)
x = model.matrix(data=mtcars, mpg ~ scale(hp)) #set up data
y = mtcars$mpg

fit=train(x, y, method="svmLinear") #train

svp = fit$finalModel #extract s4 model object

plot(x, xlab="", ylab="")
w <- colSums(coef(svp)[[1]] * x[unlist(alphaindex(svp)),])
b <- b(svp)
abline(b/w[1],-w[2]/w[1], col='red')
abline((b+1)/w[1],-w[2]/w[1],lty=2, col='red')
abline((b-1)/w[1],-w[2]/w[1],lty=2, col='red')
```

[image]

And your second question:

```
x = model.matrix(data=mtcars, mpg ~ scale(hp) + scale(wt) - 1) #set up data
fit=train(x, y, method="svmLinear") #train

svp = fit$finalModel #extract s4 model object

plot(x, xlab="", ylab="")
w <- colSums(coef(svp)[[1]] * x[unlist(alphaindex(svp)),])
b <- b(svp)
abline(b/w[1],-w[2]/w[1], col='red')
abline((b+1)/w[1],-w[2]/w[1],lty=2, col='red')
abline((b-1)/w[1],-w[2]/w[1],lty=2, col='red')
```

[image]

**Edit**

The above answer concerns plotting a boundary, not the linear SVM regression line.  To answer the question, one easy way to get the line is to extract the predicted values and plot the regression. You actually only need a couple of points to get the line, but for simplicity, I used the following code.

`abline(lm(predict(fit, newdata=mtcars) ~ mtcars$hp), col='green')`

or

`abline(lm(predict(fit) ~ mtcars$hp), col='green')`

[image]

Comment: OK @danielson thanks for the input though I'm not satisfied yet, what I really looking for is the *y=a+b.x* (or *y=a+b.x1+c.x2* in second case) equation of the svm regression line, with coef in original scale... something I can present to the client... (and in your answer I don't understand how my first 2D-plot became a 1-D plot without y.. ?) :-)

Comment: Sorry. I think I misunderstood the question, as I was plotting the decision boundary.  The model coefficients aren't stored in the object, so the fastest/easiest/cleanest way to get it would be `summary(lm(predict(fit) ~ mtcars$hp))` .  Are you looking for a method to generate the coefficients directly from the vectors?

Comment: OK, the `lm` on the predicted vector is a nice trick. Hadn't thought if this, thanks that was what I needed. If you want you can add this to your answer and I accept it